# Unable to convert the scientific notation to float type python

Tags: python

`a =  6.2e-05`

I have tried the below methods:

1. `a = float("{:.6f}".format(float(a)))`
2. `format(a,'f')`
3. `pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.6f}".format`

I am able to print the `a` variable as (`'0.000062'`) but the type changed into `string`. I need to convert the `a` (variable) to (`0.000062`) as the `float` type without round. Is there any method to achieve it?

Comment: `6.2e-05` is float type python. If you will use it to calculation then it will gives the same result as `0.000062`. And if you want to display then convert to string to have expected value on screen.

Comment: you has to use `"{:,.6f}".format` instead of `"{:,.4f}".format` because `0.000062` has 6 digits after dot, not 4

Comment: You have no control over the way Python represents a float internally (which isn't decimal anyway). What you see when it is output is *always* a sequence of characters giving a decimal representation, in other words a string, whether you store that string in a variable or not.

Answer (score 1):

6.2e-05 and 0.000062 both values are same so you can use any of these in your code.
But if you want to print the value as 0.000062 you can use this:

```
a =  6.2e-05
print("{:.6f}".format(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you check `6.2e-05 == 0.000062` it returns True.  the numbers are the same.

if you try to set the value of a variable to 0.000062 and then print the variable it will print 6.2e-05.

the numbers are the same and they will go to 6.2e-05 why would you need 0.000062 not as a string if it is the same as 6.2e-05 for math?